# How to queue print of multiple section of HTML file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

[image]

Above image shows different part of html file representing single page that should be printed separately. Is there anyway to queue a print order from javascript, to contents of each div element separately?

**CSS:**

```
.AMini
{
    height:70mm;
    width:50mm;
    background-color: white;
    border: 5px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
    float:left;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="AMini">
    <h1>Page 1</h1>
</div>


<div class="AMini">
    <h1>Page 2</h1>
</div>


<div class="AMini">
    <h1>Page 3</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you on about page breaking??  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `print` media query in combination with `page-break-after` you should be able to define a style for the printer which stacks up the three divs and puts page breaks between them.

Something like:

```
@media print 
{
    body * 
    {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .AMini, .AMini *
    {
        visibility: visible;
    }

    .AMini
    {
        page-break-after: always;
        float: none;
        position: absolute;
        display:block;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that will do. When I am using export as pdf or viewing a print preview. It spits up the pages. But there is an extra blank  page. May be because we have used here a page-break-after. Anyway we can remove the last blank page?

Comment: we can add a class to the last div and reset `page-break-after` to `auto`. alternatively if the last div is that final child element we could add a rule for using `:last-child`

Comment: Another question off topic if you don't mind.  I am trying to build a dynamic report generator, report has static content mostly, but have some parts which will be changed dynamically by the input taken from user through some forms. So I want each section of report to be printed separately. Is my approach correct or you can suggest something better? :)

Comment: Sounds like a sensible approach. This is what the print media query and page-break-after are there for :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try an approach where you assign each `div` a class called `hidden`, and then in CSS make it `visibility: hidden;`. When you approach the bottom of the page (you can find this with JavaScript and/or JQuery), then use JavaScript to set the visibility to visible: `document.getElementById('page1div').style.visibility = 'visible'`. You could even use JQuery to animate this.

This is another approach:

```
 <style>
.break { page-break-before: always; }
</style>
<body>
content on page 1...
<h1 class="break">text of Heading 1 on page 2</h1>
content on page 2...
<h1 class="break">text of Heading 1 on page 3</h1>
content on page 3...
<p class="break">content on top of page 4</p>
content on page 4...
</body>
```

Here, the pages are broken, and are displayed all at once. I was not sure what you were referring to, but these would work.

Good luck!